# Connecting to both broadband network and wifi network in Android shell

Tags: android, networking

I want to use both wifi and broadband in my Android phone. I have rooted and I managed to get both network interfaces to be up with command `ifconfig wlan0/rmnet0 up`. But I am not able to obtain the ip address. There are no dhcpd or dhclient commands. What can I do with it, please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dhcpcd command. E.g. `dhcpcd -p wlan0`.